# Expectation of an absolute value of a normal random variate

Tags: probability

Given that a random variable $X$ is a normally distributed variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Why exactly is:

$$\mathbb{E}[|X|] = \mathbb{E}[X\mid X>0]P(X>0) - \mathbb{E}[X\mid X<0]P(X<0)$$

Because we have that:

$$\mathbb{E}[X\mid X>0] = \frac{\int_0^\infty xf_X(x)\,dx}{P(X>0)}$$

Therefore my definition immediately above must be incorrect?

Because if it is not we have that:

$$\mathbb{E}[|X|] = \int_0^\infty xf_X(x)\,dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 xf_X(x)\,dx$$

and where does the minus there come from anyway, and why?

Comment: If $X<0$, then $\lvert X\rvert = -X$. Hence the minus sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}(|X|) & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |x| f_X(x)\,dx \\[10pt]
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |x| \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx \tag a \\[10pt]
& = 2 \int_0^\infty x \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \,dx & & \left( \begin{array}{l} \text{since the function} \\  \text{in line (a) is even,} \end{array} \right) \\[10pt]
& = \frac 2 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2} \Big(x\,dx\Big) & & \text{HINT!} \\[10pt]
& = \frac 2 {\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-u} \,du & & \left( \begin{array}{l} \text{So the hint wasn't needed} \\  \text{since I gave you this.} \end{array} \right) \\[10pt]
& = \text{what?}
\end{align}
When $x=0$ then $u=0$ and as $x\to\infty$ then $u\to\infty$, so the bounds of integration do not change when the substitution is done.

Can you do the rest?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[|X|] = \int^\infty_0 x f_X(x) dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 x f_X(x)dx$

Comment: and therefore what I have written there is correct... Thanks

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal : Someone pointed out in the comments that when $x$ is negative then $|x| = -x$, and that's where the minus sign comes from. I didn't mention that in my answer; one may hope that you got that point anyway. $\qquad$

Comment: Yes I did. And i suspected that would be the case. I asked it anyway because i was not sure about pulling out of constants inside expectation when it is a conditional expectation. But obviously you can still do that. So that is how we get a minus

Comment: Why did you assume a standard normal here?

Comment: @Iamanon :  Yes, this is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

In general if $\mathbb{E}\left|X\right|<\infty$ then:

$$\mathbb{E}\left|X\right|=$$$$\mathbb{E}\left(\left|X\right|\mid X>0\right)P\left(X>0\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(\left|X\right|\mid X=0\right)P\left(X=0\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(\left|X\right|\mid X<0\right)P\left(X<0\right)=$$$$\mathbb{E}\left(\left|X\right|\mid X>0\right)P\left(X>0\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(\left|X\right|\mid X<0\right)P\left(X<0\right)$$

Also:

- $\left|X\right|=X$ under condition $X>0$
- $\left|X\right|=-X$ under condition $X<0$ .

So we end up with:

$$\mathbb{E}\left|X\right|=$$$$\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid X>0\right)P\left(X>0\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(-X\mid X<0\right)P\left(X<0\right)=$$$$\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid X>0\right)P\left(X>0\right)-\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid X<0\right)P\left(X<0\right)$$