# How to prove the correctness of this expression for a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

> Докажите, что если $\xi \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, то
>   $$ \mathsf{M}(|\xi|) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma,\qquad
> \mathsf{D}(|\xi|) = \left(1-\frac{2}{\pi}\right)\sigma^2. $$

(Or, in English:)

> Prove that if $\xi \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, then
>   $$ \mathsf{M}(|\xi|) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma,\qquad
> \mathsf{D}(|\xi|) = \left(1-\frac{2}{\pi}\right)\sigma^2. $$

I tried to solve this problem with using definition of the mathematical expectation ($\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\,dx)$, but he is not taken.

Comment: Please try to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math here.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814878/expectation-of-an-absolute-value-of-a-normal-random-variate. The variance follows from the mean.